# OpenCV Android Linking CXX shared library FAILED

Tags: android, c++, cmake, clang++

I'm trying to build a VINS app on android platform, and I'm facing some library linking error. Seems it could not find gomp, but it's included in the target target_link_libraries in the CMakeLists.txt.
Could anyone provide me any hints on solving this problem? Many thanks!

```
Execution failed for task ':app:buildCMakeRelease'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /Users/sue/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/ninja with arguments {-C /Users/sue/Documents/Vins-On-Android-master4/Vins-Droidcv310/app/.cxx/Release/l4h4jp5k/arm64-v8a native-lib}
  ninja: Entering directory `/Users/sue/Documents/Vins-On-Android-master4/Vins-Droidcv310/app/.cxx/Release/l4h4jp5k/arm64-v8a'
  [1/1] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cxx/Release/l4h4jp5k/obj/arm64-v8a/libnative-lib.so
  FAILED: ../../../../build/intermediates/cxx/Release/l4h4jp5k/obj/arm64-v8a/libnative-lib.so 
  : && /Users/sue/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/sue/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/sue/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/sysroot -fPIC -isystem /Users/sue/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -std=c++0x -O2 -DNDEBUG  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -nostdlib++ --sysroot /Users/sue/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -L/Users/sue/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ../../../../build/intermediates/cxx/Release/l4h4jp5k/obj/arm64-v8a/libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/estimator_node.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/parameters.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/estimator.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/feature_manager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/factor/pose_local_parameterization.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/factor/projection_factor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/factor/marginalization_factor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/utility/utility.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/utility/visualization.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/initial/solve_5pts.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/initial/initial_aligment.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/initial/initial_sfm.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/initial/initial_ex_rotation.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/loop-closure/ThirdParty/DBoW/BowVector.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/loop-closure/ThirdParty/DBoW/FBrief.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/loop-closure/ThirdParty/DBoW/FeatureVector.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/loop-closure/ThirdParty/DBoW/QueryResults.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/loop-closure/ThirdParty/DBoW/ScoringObject.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/loop-closure/ThirdParty/DUtils/Random.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/loop-closure/ThirdParty/DUtils/Timestamp.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/loop-closure/ThirdParty/DVision/BRIEF.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/loop-closure/ThirdParty/VocabularyBinary.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/loop-closure/loop_closure.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/loop-closure/keyframe.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/loop-closure/keyframe_database.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/feature_tracker/feature_tracker.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/camera_model/src/chessboard/Chessboard.cc.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/camera_model/src/calib/CameraCalibration.cc.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/camera_model/src/camera_models/Camera.cc.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/camera_model/src/camera_models/CameraFactory.cc.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/camera_model/src/camera_models/CostFunctionFactory.cc.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/camera_model/src/camera_models/PinholeCamera.cc.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/camera_model/src/camera_models/CataCamera.cc.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/camera_model/src/camera_models/EquidistantCamera.cc.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/camera_model/src/camera_models/ScaramuzzaCamera.cc.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/camera_model/src/sparse_graph/Transform.cc.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/camera_model/src/gpl/gpl.cc.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/camera_model/src/gpl/EigenQuaternionParameterization.cc.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/a2ir/log_util.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/a2ir/phone_sensor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/a2ir/timer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/draw_result/delaunay.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/draw_result/draw_result.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/vins_estimator/src/draw_result/triangle.cpp.o  ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java3.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_calib3d.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_core.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_features2d.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_flann.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_highgui.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_imgcodecs.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_imgproc.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_ml.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_objdetect.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_photo.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_shape.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_stitching.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_superres.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_ts.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_video.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_videoio.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_videostab.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libceres.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libboost_filesystem-gcc-mt-1_53.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libboost_program_options-gcc-mt-1_53.a ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libboost_system-gcc-mt-1_53.a -landroid -llog -lgomp -latomic -lm "/Users/sue/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so" && :
  /Users/sue/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: cannot find -lgomp
  clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I downloaded a libceres.a from others and put into the jinLibs in the project, then I'm facing the error of Linking CXX shared library.

Comment: It can't find libgomp

Comment: "Seems it could not find gomp, but it's included in the target target_link_libraries in the CMakeLists.txt." - The linker **looks for** libgomp library because your `CMakeLists.txt` has corresponding `target_link_libraries` call. You got the error because the linker **failed to find** libgomp library **on your machine**. So, do you have libgomp library installed?